# iphone - UIGestureRecognizer prevents UITableView from scrolling in Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have added two swipe gesture recognizers (swipe left and swipe right) to my `UITableView`. After that my table view has stopped scrolling. At the same time `-(void)didSelectRowAtIndex` works fine.
What might be the problem?

All I did is drag-and-dropped Swipe Gesture Recognizers from objects library onto my UITableView.

If I remove them, my table starts to scroll again.

**UPD:**

This happens after upgrading to Xcode 4.5. There is no such problem in older versions of Xcode.
To avoid this behaviour - add `UIGestureRecognizers` programatically, not in IB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just try bellow code may this help you.... 
write bellow code in `viewDidLoad:` method

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureObjectImg = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourSlideOpen_Clicked:)] autorelease];//yourSlideOpen_Clicked is method name where you doing something
swipeGestureObjectImg.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeGestureObjectImg.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft);
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureObjectImg];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRightObjectImg = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourSlideClose_Clicked:)] autorelease];//yourSlideClose_Clicked is method name where you doing something
swipeGestureRightObjectImg.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeGestureRightObjectImg.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight);
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRightObjectImg];
```

if here tableview is subview of UIView class then use above code otherwise just try "youtTableview" insted of "yourView"

i hope this help you...

:)

Comment: Yes, it worked after adding them programatically. Such problem happens after updating to Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 1):

set property of gesture recognizer cancelsTouchesInView = NO

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it doesn't help in Xcode 4.5 (if you added it non programmatically) :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: 
I used to drag my TabGestureRecognizer directly onto the storyboard instead of creating them through code. With iOS6 this now seems to break scrolling.

I prefer adding views, gestures, etc directly onto the storyboard instead of through code.

You can still do this but with two changes:

1) Referencing Outlet Collections

- Right-click the GestureRecognizer which is visible to you within the scene's dock.
- Clear the section Referencing Outlet Collections

2) Attach the GestureRecognizer to the related view through code

- Create an outlet for your GestureRecognizer
- Add the following line within the viewDidLoad method:

  `[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:_tabGesture];`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem and I solved it by linking the gesture recognizer to the view instead of to the table view.

1. Show the storyboard.
2. Show the connections inspector.
3. Show the document outline.
4. Create new link at "Referencing Outlet Collections" between gesture recognizer and view node under the view controller.

Regards.
Pedro.