# what's wrong with xcode 4.5 and UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

I recently downloaded the latest stable release of xcode 4.5 but when I tried to compile my project, everything worked fine, except that all my scrollview stopped scrolling ! 
(with ios 6.0, ios 5.1 and ios 5.0)

I downloaded the previous version of xcode to see if it has something to do with my code, but it's working with xcode_4.4.1 .

When I want to access to any of a scrollview's properties, my application crashes ! 
I checked with the zombie inspector and it seems that they are deallocated. How so ? 
it was working before.

What has changed concerning this topic with xcode 4.5 ?

My scrollviews are created with the storyboard and linked with IBOutlets. 
Do you have any ideas to where I can look ?

Comment: I have the same problem, but my app does not crash when I'm accessing my scrollview-s variables. It just doesn't scroll. All other touches on the view are registered no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have gesture recognizers set up in that Scene in the Storyboard? If so try to remove them in the storyboard and add them programmatically. See this question: [iphone - UIGestureRecognizer prevents UITableView from scrolling in Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423253/iphone-uigesturerecognizer-prevents-uitableview-from-scrolling-in-xcode-4-5)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have several gesture recognizers. I will try that tomorrow.