# UIScrollView does not scroll when an object is inside

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I made a `UIScrollView` inside a `UIViewController` **I have like 5 ViewControllers** my `problem is in the 4th one`.

The `UIScrollView` I made does scroll when I put notting it it (so no label no button, no objects at all) but when I put even a label (or anything) in the `UIScrollView` it stops working.

Edit:

I have try'd making the same thing in a new project, for some reason it does work I think it has something to do with the fact that it is **in the 4th ViewController** and the new one I made, was made, **in the First automatically made viewcontroller**.
I do not yet have a answer please help.

My code:
viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface viewcontroller : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollerMdon;

@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
@synthesize ScrollerMdon;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *) nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *) nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self)
    {

    }
return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[ScrollerMdon setScrollEnabled:YES];
[ScrollerMdon setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1000)];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

In xcode viewcontroller connection inspector my outlet `ScrollerMdon` is connected with **Scroll View(**which I inserted in my viewcontroller)

In xcode `UIScrollView` connection inspector my Referencing outlet `ScrollerMdon` is connected with viewcontroller.

Please help me I have been trying to solve this for 5 hours.. I can't stand it anymore.

Edit:

I try to make it possible for a single viewcontroller to hold like 17 textboxes I see no other way than doing it with a `UIScrollView` if there are any suggestions I would be really happy.

Edit2:

I have try'd to make it all aggain putting the same class on a different view controller and the other way around, I kinda rewrote the code and everything it's exactly the same as what I made in the other project but it does not work.(when an object is inside..)

2 foto's of my program.
Srry for the small and bad images, for some reason they moved without my permision but it is enough information I guess.(I use VMWare 8 with os x leopard on it)

[foto 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTQuG.png)

[foto 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmZBZ.png)

Me Scrolling without items: 
 imgur.com/cd16I

Me desperately Scrolling with items:
 imgur.com/hNUl1

Since I can only post 2 hyperlinks you have to open these yourself.
PS. please upvote this if you do not know the answer for I need a answer and there will probably be more viewers if it gets upvoted, ty.

Edit3:

I am now copying my entire code and build of the app in a different project hope this wil work :S.

Comment: Please show us the code how you put or add any object in scrollview the problem is lies in that code :)

Comment: Check if user interaction is enabled for that object in interface builder.

Comment: I try'd doing this but this did not work. also if you look in my edit I basically made the same thing but in a different project in that project the labels interaction wasn't enabled either but they did work!

Comment: When you say the 4th view controller you mean your 4th screen? Are you replacing your view controller's view or placing the scroll view inside it? Let met suggest you something that is completely off topic, but you shouldn't name your non-static variables or properties with capital letters as first letter. First time I looked I thought I was seeing some class.

Comment: I do mean the 4th screen and Wolvorin what do you mean by "show us the code how you put or add any object" (or where can I find it?)
I add the labels in the scrollview by simply sweeping them in, also I put my scroll view inside my viewcontrollers view.

Comment: If you use gestureRecognizers look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423253/iphone-uigesturerecognizer-prevents-uitableview-from-scrolling-in-xcode-4-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution it might not be the perfect solution but it works.

The problem seemed to be somewhere in my first project since I could make it work in other projects,
so I copy'd my entire project to a different project and this way it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I had the SAME exact problem that I ran into yesterday.  Drove me nuts for hours... This was a brand new project that I just started like a week or so ago.

The thing is, I had another project that had the exact same setup essentially that I had started last summer that has no problems.  Tabbed application, VC that has a UIScrollView with many uiviews, labels, images etc... works great.

So what changed from that project to this project?  The version of Xcode that I started the project out in.  The project from last summer did NOT have the AutoLayout enabled as an option.  This new one did ( Xcode 4.6 ).

If I turn off "Use AutoLayout" for the entire project it works fantastic.

In the Utilities panel, click on the File Inspector tab.  In the section for "Interface Builder Document" you'll see a checkbox for "Use AutoLayout".  De-select that and re-build your app.  Just found this trick not more than 10 minutes ago for my own project -- works great.

Hope this works for your project... good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't explain what is wrong but I think it will solve your problem.

Copy the elements from the new project you created to the old one and replace the affected view controller. Copy also the class.

There must be something wrong with your connections but with the info you provided is impossible to check.

If that doesn't work then it must be something in the navigation (doubt it) or in some custom code you have on the class (very difficult if all the code you have is in the viewDidLoad as you've shown).

Comment: I try'd your first suggestion but it does not work the items have the exact same quality's it must be something in the fact that the one that works is in a officially first created Viewcontroller, is there any special rule for using a UIScrollview in a Viewcontroller you made yourself?

Comment: The interface builder view controller is well connected with its class?

Comment: Yes the interface builder view controller is connected with its class.

Comment: The only thing now left for you to do here is post screenshots of the interface builder (view hierarchy, properties and connections) and tell how you're presenting the view controller. While you're at it try to make that view controller the initial view controller.

Comment: I really would love to do that but this was the error I got for trying: "you need at least 10 reputation to post images".

Comment: You're almost there ;) Try a free image hoster.