# UISwipeGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer in one view issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHighlightReadingVC:)];
    swipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.highlightReadingVC_.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizer];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panHighlightReadingVC:)];
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeGestureRecognizer];
    [self.highlightReadingVC_.view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

My issue is that although I am swiping on the view, it always detects the pan gesture first. I want the swipe to be recognized first before the pan/drag. How do I do that?

Comment: see my this answer may you got some idea from that for swipeGestureRecognizer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423253/iphone-uigesturerecognizer-prevents-uitableview-from-scrolling-in-xcode-4-5/12423565#12423565

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to set one of the two `UIGestureRecognizer`'s delegates to an object that makes sense (likely `self`) then listen, and return `YES`.

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

This method is called when recognition of a gesture by either `gestureRecognizer` or `otherGestureRecognizer` would block the other gesture recognizer from recognizing its gesture. Note that returning `YES` is guaranteed to allow simultaneous recognition; returning `NO`, on the other hand, is not guaranteed to prevent simultaneous recognition because the other gesture recognizer's delegate may return `YES`.

I also faced same issue in my app & it works fine for me. So it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to have **pan** gesture/s prevent recognition of **swiping** (the usual case):

```
swipeGesture.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(panGesture)
```

If the goal is to have **swipe** gesture/s prevent recognition of **panning** (the unusual case):

```
panGesture.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeGesture)
```

Also do the usual:

```
panGesture.delegate = self
swipeGesture.delegate = self
```

And implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` to always return `true`

**Note:** on things like `UIWebView`'s and `UIScrollView`'s to correctly interpret a single-touch swipe, it's best to `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` all three (3) of: a pan, a long press and a second swipe recognizer with `.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2` for the UX to work intuitively.

Here's what we use (Swift):

```
class AboutViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    var swipeToDismiss: UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        var r = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismiss:")
        r.direction = .Right
        r.delegate = self
        r.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(longPress)
        r.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(pan)
        r.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleSwipe)
        return r
    }

    var doubleSwipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        var r = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
        r.direction = .Right
        r.delegate = self
        r.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        return r
    }

    var longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
        var r = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
        r.allowableMovement = 4000.0
        r.delegate = self
        return r
    }

    var pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        var r = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        r.delegate = self
        return r
    }

    func dismiss(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!) {
         // ...popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    private func setupWebView() {
        // ...
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeToDismiss)
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleSwipe)
    }


    // MARK: - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        println("gesture start: \(gestureRecognizer)")
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        println("multiple gestures: \(gestureRecognizer), \(otherGestureRecognizer)")
        return true
    }


    // MARK: - UIViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupWebView()
    }
}
```